# How to measure the understanding level of a new concept that was taught to a group of students

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, standard-deviation, means

Let us say I am an online teacher and I have to introduce a new topic in the class today. Let us say the topic is "Solving a Quadratic Equation". There is an online community of students from different backgrounds in the class and there are approx 100 students in the class.

At the end of the class I take a short quiz to see how much the students have understood this new concept.

If I want to measure the 'understanding level' of each student on the basis of the quiz's result and quantify it then how would i do that?

How can I use any concepts like means, standard deviation, poisson's or normal distribution?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, in the future, please consider if questions like this may be better suited for the [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) SE site instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could get them to rate their own confidence in each answer from 1 to 5. Wrong answer with low confidence = no knowledge. Wrong answer with high confidence = misunderstanding. Plot the results on a scatter plot maybe?